# Is projection normal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that projection is a normal matrix? It's clear that orthogonal projection is, but what about non-orthogonal projection?

By normal matrix, I mean matrix A such that $AA' = A'A$.

Comment: Eigenspaces of a non-orthogonal projection aren't orthogonal and hence non-orthogonal projection isn't a normal operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in general. Here's a counter-example:

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0  & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$. You can easily show $A^2 = A$, so it is a projection matrix.

However, $AA^T = \begin{bmatrix} 0  & 0 \\ 0 & 5 \\ \end{bmatrix} \neq 
A^TA = \begin{bmatrix} 4  & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 3):

If fact, every non-orthogonal projection $A$ is non-normal. Indeed, the adjoint $A'$ is also a projection, and 
$$\operatorname{ran}A' = (\ker A)^\perp \ne \operatorname{ran}A$$
since $A$ is not orthogonal. If two projections commute, they must have the same range.